# Get values from Python list by key. How to achieve this?

Tags: python, list, key, key-value

I have the below values in a Python list.

```
my_list = [{'Email': 'testemail@gmail.com', 'Fax': '125485795', 'Hash': '1', 'Comment': 'Foo', 'Product': 'bar'}]
print(type(my_list))

<class 'list'>
```

Can anyone help me access each list item? For instance, how can I get the value '1' for 'Hash' item list?

Comment: You have a list containing a dictionary. Do you know how to access list elements? Or how to access values by key in a dictionary? Then *combine* those two techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_list` is just a list with a single dict inside it, so you can do:

```
my_list = [{'Email': 'testemail@gmail.com', 'Fax': '125485795', 'Hash': '1', 'Comment': 'Foo', 'Product': 'bar'}]

print(my_list[0]["Hash"]) # 1
```

Iterate over the dict's content like such:

```
for key, item in my_list[0].items():
    print("key: " + key + " - item: " + item)
```

Output:

> key: Comment - item: Foo
>
> key: Fax - item: 125485795
>
> key: Hash - item: 1
>
> key: Email - item: testemail@gmail.com
>
> key: Product - item: bar

Comment: Thank you @Ismael Padilla. This is exactly what I need.